# ios CCLabelTTF colored subclass with Core Text

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, core-text

Good day to all.

At the moment I am trying to implement CCLabelTTF subclass with suppport of NSAttributedString to get multi-colored label. And I am hampered by lack of CoreText and CoreGraphics knowledge.

After reading few guides I, created CCTexture2D category to create texture using NSAttributedString object.

Here is my drawing code:

```
data = calloc(POTHigh, POTWide * 2);

colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, POTWide, POTHigh, 8, POTWide, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

if( ! context ) 
{
    free(data);
    [self release];
    return nil;
}

UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, POTHigh);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f); 

// draw attributed string to context
CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)string);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, dimensions.width, dimensions.height));

CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);

CTFrameDraw(frame, context);

UIGraphicsPopContext();

CFRelease(frame);
CGPathRelease(path);
CFRelease(frameSetter);
```

---

And now I have few troubles:

---

The first one - my texture is shown flipped vertically. I thought, that these lines

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, POTHigh);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
```

should prevent this.

---

The second one, if I create RGB context, I cannot see anything on the screen. I tried to create RGB context with these lines.

```
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, POTWide, POTHigh, 8, POTWide * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
```

I tried to google, but don't find anything related to my issues =( Any help(links or suggestions) is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things to try:

- Your data allocation isn't big enough for RGB.  Try: `data = calloc(POTHigh, POTWide * 4);` for RGB color space.
- `CTFrameDraw` draws in relation to GL coords so you don't need to use `CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);`

  - that line was put in the original CCTexture2D creation for a CCLabelTTF because it used NSString's `drawInRect:` which draws in relation to UIKit coords.
- Maybe try other alpha mask flags...? Check out Apple's documentation on [Supported Pixel Formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) for iOS to see what your options are.

Comment: thanks for your reply. if I remove `CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f)`, there is nothing on display. data allocation didn't do anything. now trying different flags...

Comment: @Morion Try also removing `CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, POTHigh);` along with the Scale.

Comment: removed both strings, the string is displayed =) but still cannot do anythyng to draw it in RGB...

Comment: @Morion Yeah, I'm out of ideas.  I played around with `CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString` a little last night and couldn't get it to draw in color either, only shades of gray. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at ActiveTextView-iOS (https://github.com/storify/ActiveTextView-iOS). It may be of use.

Comment: thanks for this link, but this control uses current context for drawing, and I want to create my own to be able to create CCTexture2D object

Answer (score 0):

use this to get color texture:

```
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, POTWide, POTHigh, 8, POTWide, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I get this error message `<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 1024 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`